# Start Activity of one application from another application in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to android development. My teacher has set us a task to develop an application and take text input in it. Then on button click send this data to another application and display it on that application.
But when I click then button the application stops.
This is my code so far

Layout xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:onClick="function1" />
```

function1 in mainActivity.java

```
EditText myEditText;
public void function1(View v){
    String userText=myEditText.getText().toString();
    Intent i= new Intent();
    i.setAction("textViewActivity");
    i.putExtra("message", userText);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In the second application I have registered the activity as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity2"
    android:label="@string/a2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="textViewActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

in activity2.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    TextView mytextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2View1);
    String Value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("message");
    mytextView.setText(Value);
}
```

I have no idea where i did wrong. When I click button the program stops. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
logcat:

```
02-11 22:43:52.449: D/gralloc_goldfish(1092): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-11 22:43:56.759: D/AndroidRuntime(1092): Shutting down VM
02-11 22:43:56.759: W/dalvikvm(1092): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab0b90)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): Process: smd.homework1.question2, PID: 1092
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     ... 11 more
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at smd.homework1.question2.MainActivity.function1(MainActivity.java:26)
02-11 22:43:56.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: what you are getting in logcat? share that.

Comment: Without seeing logs it's really hard to know what's wrong here

Comment: @amitsingh I have updated the catlog. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @SamN-a I have updated the catlog. Sorry for the delay

Comment: What is line 26 of your MainActivity?

Comment: You've got null pointer - I think EditText isn't initialized

Comment: you editText is null. post the code where you set the view and find the edittext.

Comment: @NKN line 26 is `i.putExtra("message", userText);`

Comment: Then both @SamN-a and @njzk2 are right: Your `EditText` is `null`.

Comment: @SSMA : there is nothing that can throw an exception in this. this is not the code that causes the exception.

Comment: this is my oncreate function:
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  myEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 }`

Comment: I initialize myEditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first application you should initialize your EditText in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`:

```
 myEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.PUT_ID_HERE);
```

Also change this:

```
String userText=myEditText.getText().toString();
```

to:

```
String userText;
if(myEditText.getText()==null){
    userText = "";
}else{
    userText = myEditText.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sending data from one ACTIVITY to another ACTIVITY! is that what you teacher asked? Or he asked to send data from one APPLICATION to another APPLICATION?
if it's from one app to another app,you should implement Service and Broadcast Receiver.
if it's from one activity to another activity within one application then @Sam already answered

Answer (score 0):

First you should specify your application package as prefix to all of your custom Intent actions, so instead of

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity2"
    android:label="@string/a2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="textViewActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

try

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity2"
    android:label="@string/a2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.whatever.is.yourpackage.ACTION.textViewActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also Android puts action category DEFAULT to all implicit intents passed to startActivity(). You should add this category to your intent-filter. I strongly suggest you to read this post http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html